# Open Graph image meta tag for not found for LinkedIn only

Tags: next.js, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm trying to set up the open graph meta tags in the html on my website built with Next.js, and for some reason, the image is never found. They work on Facebook, Twitter, and WhatsApp just fine, but not LinkedIn. I also noticed it isn't working in Discord.

This is my code, wrapped within the `<Head>` element in Next.

```
<meta property='og:image' content='https://steelpoll.com/images/steelpoll.png' />
<meta property='og:image:width' content='1200' />
<meta property='og:image:height' content='627' />
<meta property='og:image:type' content='image/png' />
```

I'm using the LinkedIn Post Inspector, which you can view for my website here:
https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fwww.steelpoll.com%2F

Facebook's works correctly, seen here:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.steelpoll.com%2F

I am following the specific LinkedIn Open Graph Image guidelines found here:
https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en

My image is 51.3 KB with dimensions of 1266 x 703, which meets the minimum size. I am also manually setting the content size at 1200 x 627, a perfect 1.91:1 ratio as recommended, via the html meta tags seen below.

You can view the image at the `https://steelpoll.com/images/steelpoll.png`
You can view the meta tags in the dev console of my site at https://www.steelpoll.com/

What could I be missing?

Comment: I don’t know if it makes a difference or not, but you do have a mix of https://steelpoll... And https://www.steelpoll... Your server does a 308 Permanent Redirect (and not a 301 Moved Permanently) to send any request for a URL without the www to a URL with www. You’re doing this for the canonical URL and the OG image. It could be worth trying to configure all of your URLs to not require a redirect by your server and see what happens.

Comment: @RichDeBourke wow, great eye! Thank you so much!!!!!! That was the problem. I just needed to add the `www.` to the string and it works. I really really really appreciate it! I spent way too many hours stuck on this. You're the best!!

For anyone viewing this in the future, if you have Next.js with Vercel hosting configured to redirect traffic to one main url, make sure that is the url you are using for your meta tags!